# How to rewrite simple if-then from synchronous to asynchronous?

Tags: ajax, asynchronous

I have this code:

```
if (condition) {
    syncAjax();
}
callAfterAjaxOnlyOnce();
```

and I want to rewrite to `asyncAjax()`. But this is not okay

```
if (condition) {
    asyncAjax(callback(){callAfterAjaxOnlyOnce();});
}
```

when `condition` is `false` because `callAfterAjaxOnlyOnce()` will be executed 0 time. This is also not good

```
if (condition) {
    asyncAjax(callback(){callAfterAjaxOnlyOnce();});
}
callAfterAjaxOnlyOnce();
```

when `condition` is `true` because `callAfterAjaxOnlyOnce()` will be executed twice. If I do

```
asyncAjax(callback(){
    if (condition) {
        callAfterAjaxOnlyOnce();
    }
});
```

this is not equal with the original code, because I want perform `asyncAjax` only in case when `condition` is true.

Is it even possible to rewrite this in order to have completely equal functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `return` in the if statement so that nothing after it will be executed if the condition is true.

```
if (condition) {
    return asyncAjax(callAfterAjaxOnlyOnce);
}
callAfterAjaxOnlyOnce();
```